# Alternate session library for PHP

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am using PHP session library in my project. The problem is that **I need to serve multiple ajax request from the same session concurrently** but in php while using sessions we can process single request for a session at a time. I know if I use session_write_close() then next ajax request will execute immediately but In our scenario the session write ability must not be closed at any point.

Is there any alternate library for session handling in PHP? File based session library would be preferred and it must be non-bloking i.e; must be able to server concurrent request without the need to use session write close.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you down-vote then please write the reason in comments

Comment: Basically if you can copy and paste the title of your question into google and the top result is what you are looking for you are likely to get downvoted.

Comment: I'm voting for close because this question is a `is there?` question and it don have the format expeted by this site. Please read the faq.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own.

Documentation Here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

Tutorial Here: http://phpmaster.com/writing-custom-session-handlers/

Answer (score 1):

you might be looking for this  : https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1900

Comment: good find ... did you know about that one or did you just add more terms to the google search.

Comment: haha... if u need a library then you can put a "github:" before the search term . it is a good place for libraries, i used a password library from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Session library, you can check https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Session .

But it internally uses `session_write_close()` as stated https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Session#session-security